# Error for importing graphml file to neo4j

Tags: import, neo4j, graphml

I can't import my graphml file into neo4j using neo4j shell. I use this command:

```
 import-graphml -i C:\Users\MARIAM\Desktop\football.graphml
```

but I get this error message:

> Invalid input 'i': expected <init> (line 1, column 1 (offset: 0))
>
> "import-graphml -i C:\Users\MARIAM\Desktop\football.graphml"
> ^

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you did not install [Neo4j shell tools](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools) properly.

The error here is that import-graphml is not recognized as a command.

Answer (score 0):

to run the **Neo4j shell tools**, we need to go to the **Options->Commands Prompts-> Neo4jShell**.

And after run the command: `import-graphml -i filepath/filename`